# Understanding Derivative of MSE

Tags: linear-regression, derivative

I'm trying to understand how chain rule is working in Gradient Descent algorithm. Failing to get intuition...

better to explain on example: we are having X (training set) with [1, 1]

let `error = (y - pred)**2` (both y and pred are [1, 1])

Derivative of the error would be `2*(y-pred)`

My understanding is, above derivative would show how unit change in pred would affect error.

say,

```
error = (2-5)**2 = 9
derivative = 2*(2-5)=6
```

so unit change in "5" should change error by 6. But:

```
(2-6)**2=16
change of 7 (16-9)
```

I did few more examples and I understand that difference is usually the delta I'm changing the "5" (this case 1) squared.

Can anyone explain what I'm missing?